# Url Amigável em PHP e Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, htaccess, seo

Possuo o seguinte código php para tornar as urls do meu site amigáveis:

```
<?php
 $atual = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? $_GET['pg'] : 'home';
 $permissao = array('home', 'contato', 'sobre', 'politica');
 $pasta = 'arquivos';
   if (substr_count($atual, '/') > 0){
     $atual = explode('/', $atual);
     $pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/".$atual[0].'.php') && in_array($atual[0], $permissao)) ? $atual[0] : 'erro';
   } else {
       $pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/".$atual.'.php') && in_array($atual, $permissao)) ? $atual : 'erro';
   }
?>
```

O meu .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

Para páginas estáticas funciona perfeitamente. O problema agora é adaptar esse código para páginas dinâmicas.

No meu site eu vou precisar de uma página categoria.php e empresa.php que receberão o valor 'slug' do meu banco de dados.

As urls ficariam dessa forma:
site.com.br/categoria.php?slug=nome-da-categoria
site.com.br/empresa.php?slug=nome-da-empresa

Como transformar essas urls em:
**site.com.br/nome-da-categoria**
**site.com.br/empresa/nome-da-empresa**

Como eu deverei fazer a chamada sql nessas páginas para serem exibidos os valores do banco?
Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre SQL ou sobre como deve ficar o `.htaccess`?

Comment: Preciso saber como ficaria a chamda sql nas páginas categoria.php e empresa.php. E caso essa modificação altere alguma coisa no htaccess eu precisava saber como ficaria o novo arquivo.

Comment: do jeito que está fazendo, está deixando o PHP fazer o trabalho do Apache, sugiro que leia [Aprendendo URLs amigáveis com regras complexas](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas/)

Comment: No `.htaccess` escreve uma nova expressao para url, e defina os parametros no categoria.php e empresa.php

Comment: [URL's amigáveis : sem dores de cabeça](https://t.co/EchXRs37zR)

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive a mesma experiência com um cliente uma vez.

Para isso eu fiz da seguinte forma e deu certo:

**index.php**

```
$pagina = $_GET['pg']; //peguei a página.php

$pagina = (isset($pagina)) ? $pagina : 'home';

//agora vou verificar se exite algum valor depois da '/'. 
if(substr_count($pagina , '/') > 0) {

    //se existir, vou atribuir o valor à uma variável que chamarei de $slug aonde farei o get mais tarde.
    $pagina = explode('/',$pagina);
    $slug= $pagina[1]; // repare que a posição do valor é a segunda, ou seja, depois da barra
    include($pagina[0].".php") ;// inclua a pagina que o usuário escolheu (exemplo: empresa.php)

} else {

     // se não existir, o $slug será nulo, mas mesmo assim incluiremos a pagina.php.
     $slug = 0; 
     include($pagina.".php") ; 

}
```

Ou seja, através desse código, você consegue fazer o get da slug quando ele existir na url.

Exemplo com a url:

```
www.site.com.br/empresa/stack-exchange
```

**empresa.php**

```
<?php

$selecionaEmpresa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE slugEmpresa = '$slug'");
//verifica se não existe esta empresa no DB
if(mysql_num_rows($selecionaEmpresa) == 0){
    //Se não existir inclua uma pagina geral estática (pode ter a lista das empresas por exemplo)
    include(geral.php);

} else {
    // mas se existir ele fará um looping e resgatar as informações desta empresa no DB
    while($empresaSelecionada = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaEmpresa)){
?>

    <div><?php echo $empresaSelecionada['conteudo']; ?> </div>

    <?php 
    } } 
    //fecha o else e o looping 
    ?>
```

com a categoria é a mesma coisa sem modificar o index

só que o arquivo se chamará **categoria.php**

com o link:

```
www.site.com.br/categoria/nome-da-categoria
```

você fará outra seleção

```
$selecionaEmpresa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE categoriaEmpresa = '$slug'");
```

boa sorte!