# Pegar parâmetros de URL em PHP

Tags: php

Endereço `http://exemplo/registrar.php`

Por exemplo, gostaria de realizar um registro pelo `registrar.php` passando os dados através de barras.

Exemplo `http://exemplo/registrar/nomedapessoa`

Como eu poderia fazer isso no PHP?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Url Amigável em PHP e Sql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48986/url-amig%c3%a1vel-em-php-e-sql)

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar `.htaccess` acaso esteja usando o Apache.

Crie um arquivo chamado `.htaccess` na pasta principal do seu site e adicione o seguinte conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Verifica se o arquivo existir então ignora a reescrita
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Verifica se a pasta existir então ignora a reescrita
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Reescreve a URL para acessar arquivos PHP e o PATH_INFO
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [L,QSA]
```

O código do php para testes deve ficar algo como (seria o registrar.php):

```
<?php
echo 'Path: ', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '<br>';

//Extraindo PATH_INFO
$paths = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($paths);

echo '</pre>';
```

Então basta acessar `http://exemplo/registrar/nomedapessoa` que será mostrado o conteudo do `http://exemplo/registrar.php/nomedapessoa`